# my parallax accelerate in unity2D when he has a new position

Tags: unity-game-engine

i'm quite new with unity, and i try to do a "flappy bird" where my obstacl is a parallax.

But i don't understand why.

When my object.x is on "-10", i just want to move it to object.x = 10.

There is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class gotoleft : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Vector3 jump;
    public float jumpForce = 0f;

    public bool isGrounded;
    Rigidbody2D rb;
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        jump = new Vector3(-1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        Debug.Log("X: " + rb.transform.position);

    }


    void FixedUpdate()
    {

            rb.AddForce(jump * jumpForce * Time.deltaTime, ForceMode2D.Impulse);

            if (rb.transform.position.x <= -40)
            {
                Debug.Log("OUAIS MEC");

                 rb.transform.position = new Vector3(10, 3.0, 0.0);


        }

    }
}
```

the position of my object is okay, but it accelerates.

If someone can explains me, thanks
I searched on the unity doc, but i still have the same pb.

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: In general don't use the `transform` when dealing with physics .. rather do check and set `rb.position` directly. Also you are adding a force every fixed update call .. is this intended? You say your object accelerates .. yes this is what happens if you continously add a force to an object ...

Comment: what is the thing that accelerates? This code has nothing to do with parallax. Please put more effort into your making your question clearer next time.

Comment: Yea I think your question is a bit confusing but I think I understand? This script will move the object from right to left until it hit -40 at which points it resets to 10. The acceleration is because you are adding force (AddForce) constantly so the object will keep going faster. If you only want it to go at the constant speed you can instead rb.velocity = somevalue. If this script is for a background piece though i'd suggest removing any rigibody from it and simply calculate the position it should be in every frame.

Comment: you are right! thanks for your answer! i just add a velocity and it was good. And sorry if my question is quite ununderstable,i was quite lost :)

Comment: @leoQuint you can add this answer, i will validate it

Answer (score 0):

If you making "flappy bird", basically you do not need to move bird itself. You must move obstacles and bg elements.

I do not see rest of your code but most likely you moving bird, what means what when your bird will fly over +40 units on "X" all your obstacle moves will become outside current camera position.

Answer (score 0):

Divide by the distance if you need only a simple parallax effect.

Make adjustments as you need.

Worth checking in Wikipedia "Perspective Projection" in the "Formula" section.